# Cloud Foundry Maven Resolve Dependencies on Platform?

Tags: java, maven, cloud-foundry

Is anyone aware of a way to deploy a maven application via cloud foundry that will:

1) Take only the application bits and upload them

2) Run the maven build based on the pom.xml

3) pull down the defined dependencies *on the platform*

Thereby NOT uploading the dependencies from the client to the platform?

Comment: You could certainly create a custom buildpack that did such a thing, but I'm not clear why you would want to do this. Cloud Foundry is not intended to be your compiler environment.

Comment: @CorbyPage For my jar-with-deps, around 56megs, I continually get timeouts and failed uploads.  So, I want to turn that into several small downloads at the platforms.  Any idea what the level of difficulty would be?

Comment: It's not trivial, but more importantly you are losing your ability to ensure consistent deployments in your cloud environment if you are attempting to rebuild the application every time you restage or bring up a new instance. I would focus on what is preventing you from being able to upload a 56 meg jar. That should not be an obstacle in a CF deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku Java buildpack does exactly what is described in the question:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java